# Triage, что это?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Увидел на en.SO ревью Triage. У нас такого нет...

Теперь вопросы(2):

- Что это за очередь?
- Почему у нас такого нет?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251737/triage-and-help-improvement-review-queues-at-sites-other-than-stack-overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Суть в простом отделении полного шлака от того, что ещё можно спасти дабы не нагружать другие очереди раньше времени.

У нас этого нет, потому что объёмы сообщений, требующих проверок, совсем не те, что на enSO.

Для справки см. [насколько ruSO не дотягивает до enSO](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-questions).